# Use thread pool in Android that's conscious of system resources

Tags: android, threadpoolexecutor

I'm trying to write some background services on android and right now I have created my own thread pool to handle them.

The services are running on a machine that will potentially have a game in the foreground and I'd like the game to have priority over the system resources.

Is there a way to make a thread pool conscious of the system's idle resources and only use what's free at that time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest to start by doing

```
Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
```

in all threads in your pool. This controls the Thread's Linux Priority. Check out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#setThreadPriority(int) for a list of constants available.

Basically, the `int` value ranges from -20 (very urgent) to 20 (least).

- The suggested `THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND` is 10
- In the docs about the constant `THREAD_PRIORITY_LOWEST`  (19): "Lowest available thread priority. **Only for those who really, really don't want to run if anything else is happening.**"

Comment: Very nice. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

Threads that are executed in a service by default will be executed in the background. The OS will shutdown the services if the system will start to run low on resources.

For the sake of simplicity you can use AsyncTask to run your threads, AsyncTask is using a threadpool so the cost of starting a thread is cheap, be aware that by default they will run in serial.